# Git changes the transparent background of .png files?

Tags: git, png, transparency

Have you experienced that you create a .png file with transparent background and is displayed fine in your local environment, but when you pull the changes from the live site, the images are displayed with a white background? why is happen that? have you solved that issue? how? (different than upload directly the .png files)

Comment: If, instead of using git to deploy the file, you were to `ftp` or `sftp` it to the live site, does it still happen?  But it would be *amazing* if git was accidentally doing this...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say with 99% certainty, that this is *not* git's doing. Git is in the business of tracking file changes, not making them. And it if it was somehow git, there would be an indication of the changes in the log (which you can check with `git log`). More specifics on your dev/prod environments, and a link to the png in question, would help diagnose the problem. My guess would be that this is an environment issue.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I agree, and was found the issue: were overwritten the images before commit moment, and aplication cache on local were displaying the transparent background images.

Comment: Please add that as an answer to the question to close the issue for good.

Comment: Glad you sorted it. Cheers!